# how can i align widgets without disturbing tthe order of other widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i'm working on a project and just learning tkinter by using it.This is the code

```
def check():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    button_exit = ttk.Button(root, text='<-----', command=main_window)
    button_exit.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1, sticky='nsew')

    set_word = ttk.Button(root, text='Set words', command=on_list_click_set)
    set_word.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    delete_word = ttk.Button(root, text='Delete words', command=on_list_click_delete)
    delete_word.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

    for i in range(1, 20):
        root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

    for i in range(1, 20):
        root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
    scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=20, rowspan=19, sticky='nsew')

    mylist = tk.Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, selectbackground="#a6a6a6",
                        selectforeground="black", exportselection=False, height=19, selectmode="single",
                        bg="#f0f0f0", relief="flat", bd=0, font=('Helvetica', 15))

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM words')
    conn.commit()

    for line in c.fetchall():
        mylist.insert(0, line[0])

    mylist.grid(row=2, column=19, rowspan=19, sticky='nsew')
    scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)

    root.update_idletasks()  # Update the layout immediately

    label_change_word = ttk.Label(root, text='Which word would you like your words to be updated to?',
                                  font=('Helvetica', 13))
    label_change_word.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, column=6, sticky='w')

    changing_word_entry = ttk.Entry(root, font=('Helvetica', 15))
    changing_word_entry.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, column=5)

    changing_word_submit = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit')
    changing_word_submit.grid(row=2, column=7)


# Rest of your code...
```

the issue is when the submit entry and label widgets appear the whole order changes along.what i mean is delete and set buttons slides a bit left and that's not okay. How can i fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsTXb.png)
this changes to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ4Cv.png)
this

Comment: I'm not able to run your example but try using `uniform = True` on all row/column configure.

Comment: @Rauf İlyai. What are you attempting to do? Are you attempting resizing window?

Comment: This is just a part of my code what i want is like i mentioned before to make delete and set widgets not change their place not slide left i attached 2 pictures actually you can check it out. When i click on set button 3 widgets appear right next to them and that 3 widgets pushes delete and set buttons to left what i want is make the widgets not slide just stand where they are

Comment: It work for me under Python3.12.0rc3. Not uisng sql